# Is there any hope to find the general function $f(x,y)$ if we know the function value at two points as given?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, multivalued-functions

I am looking for a general function $f(x,y)$ for which I have

$$ (x_0,y_0)=(3,1) \quad \text{we have} \quad f(x_0,y_0)=12 $$
and
$$ (x_1,y_1)=(5,1) \quad \text{we have} \quad f(x_1,y_1)=5(23-\sqrt{5})$$

Are these data sufficient to find such a function?

Comment: No. You only know two values of the function, and nothing more.

Comment: @pancini Thanks. Do you mean that if I have more points, it will be a chance?

Comment: A general function? Absolutely not. If you say why you thought there might be, or what use you'd want to make of such a thing if it existed, people here might be able to help you better. But your problem, as stated, just gets a "no".

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thanks, unfortunately, there is a long story behind this question!

Comment: It may be easier to see why this is insufficient if you consider the simpler case of a function of a single variable $f(x)$. If all you had were two points, you obviously could not generate the entire function from those two points. *unless* you knew more about the function. If you knew that it was linear, for example, then there's only one line passing through the two points. Or if you knew that it was a parabola that also passed through the origin, that would be enough. But unconstrained, it's not possible, and having the additional degree of freedom of a second variable only makes it worse.

Comment: For some intuition about a function of two variables, you can picture the graph which is a surface. Think of $x$ and $y$ as longitude and latitude on a map and the output values as the elevation of the ground. What you have provided is the elevation at only two points. There are of course infinitely many surfaces that pass through those two points.

Comment: Is your question how to find a supposed "unique" function passing through those points, or is it just how to find some function that does? The first interpretation is what your title suggests, talking about "the" function, but the second is what the question itself suggests, talking about "such a function". The answer to the first is "no", as everyone has said. But the answer to the second interpretation is "yes, quite easily". For example, you could have $f$ be the plane passing through those two points and the origin.